# OnNavigatedTo called before page has loaded in iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, prism

I've noticed that when running the iOS version on an iPhone that my viewmodel is being loaded and the OnNavigatedTo is being called before the page actually shows up on the screen and it's leading to some strange behaviour when logic in the OnNavigatedTo doesn't correspond to what's on the screen.

Firstly, is this correct behaviour?

Secondly, is there any way to determine when the page has actually displayed?

Comment: I have a very similar issue. I have a Login page solely on the stack. After successful login, I NavigateAsync() to an absolute path to eliminate the login page & replace with /MainPage/NavigationPage/LandingPage. When this navigation occurs the Login page remains in view even while the LandingPage.OnNavigatedTo() is executing. This causes issues with way I apply a Loading indicator as the indicator displays briefly before the Login page disappears, and then doesn't show on the Landing page while the code is executing, as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnNavigatedTo is called directly after the call to Xamarin.Forms Navigation.PushModalAsync or Navigation.PushAsync.  It's the last step in the navigation process.  You can see that here:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Forms/Navigation/PageNavigationService.cs#L353

Depending on how complicated your view is and how much needs to render, it might cause a delay in the rendering of your View.  I'm not sure how any code in OnNavigatedTo would lead to any strange behavior because at least all your data should already be loaded and ready to display.

Comment: So there is no way to know when it renders?

I have two pages having issues. The first one uses a hybrid web view and I'd like to execute some javascript once it's loaded. The second one starts polling for a connection and it's stopping the page loading. I guess the second one could be an issue with accidentally blocking the main thread but still it could be solved by a on rendered event.

Comment: Not that I can think of.  Even the Page.OnAppearing happens prior to the Page becoming visible. 

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnAppearing/

Your second issue can be solved by making it async regardless of when the page becomes visible.